# Why Valgrind complains about fgets?

Tags: c, valgrind, fopen

I have a simple C code.

**main.c**

```
int main() {
    FILE *stream = fopen("../input.txt", "r");
    cube test_cube;
    cube_initialization(&test_cube, stream);

/* and some code with free memory which is not needed to understand the situation */

}
```

**cube.c**

```
/* just the function valgrind complains about */

void cube_initialization(cube *cube, FILE *input_file) {
    int side_length;
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    char waste_buffer[BUF_SIZE];


    fgets(buffer, BUF_SIZE, input_file);
    fgets(waste_buffer, BUF_SIZE, input_file); /* empty line */
    side_length = (int) strtol(buffer, NULL, 10);
    cube->side_length = side_length;
    cube->cube_array = malloc(side_length * sizeof(int **));
    int z;
    for (z = 0; z < side_length; z++) {
        cube->cube_array[z] = malloc(side_length * sizeof(int *));
        int y;
        for (y = 0; y < side_length; y++) {
            cube->cube_array[z][y] = malloc(side_length * sizeof(int));
        }
    }
}
```

and valgrind output

```
==8251== Invalid read of size 4
==8251==    at 0x48F3727: fgets (iofgets.c:47)
==8251==    by 0x1093C2: cube_initialization (cube.c:11)
==8251==    by 0x10928D: main (main.c:11)
==8251==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==8251== 
==8251== 
==8251== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==8251==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==8251==    at 0x48F3727: fgets (iofgets.c:47)
==8251==    by 0x1093C2: cube_initialization (cube.c:11)
==8251==    by 0x10928D: main (main.c:11)
==8251==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==8251==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==8251==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==8251==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==8251==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==8251== 
==8251== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8251==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8251==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 488 bytes allocated
==8251== 
==8251== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==8251== 
==8251== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==8251== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I don't understand why Valgrind complains about `fgets()`. I read data from file and use `fgets` with pointer to big buffer(256) but it needs me just for read short lines about 1-6 symbols (I need fgets because it stops when it finds '\n' at the end of line). Maybe the problem is in the fact fgets() tries to read line of 256 symbols and it stops after 1-5 and '\n'?

Comment: You forgot to verify that the file was successfully opened.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Don't tag both unless you're asking about the differences between them.

Comment: Check `stream` pointer in main after `fopen` before passing it to `cube_initialization()`

Comment: @molbdnilo thank you, it helped. Is this  because valgrind runs in its own environment and doesn't see my file ? P.s sorry for c++ tag, i thought that valgrind is a tool for C/C++ leak checking and i could tag it as c++ also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Valgrind complains about illegal address `0x0` access:

> Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

In your `fgets()` call

```
fgets(buffer, BUF_SIZE, input_file);
```

`buffer` parameter is fine because it is allocated in the stack. The only responsible can be `input_file` parameter, coming from `main()`. That parameter is a stream obtained from `fopen()` call. You didn't check it before passing to `cube_initialization()`!

Check it, and then understand why it returns NULL (probably you try to open a path that doesn't exist).

```
int main() {
    FILE *stream = fopen("../input.txt", "r");
    cube test_cube;
    if( stream != NULL )
    {
        cube_initialization(&test_cube, stream);

        /* Continue execution*/
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it returns NULL because program run in special vlagrind environment and doesn't see my path to the file. Is is correct  ?

Answer (score 3):

Valgrind complains about an invalid read in `fgets()`. The problem unlikely to be the size of the destination array, which could trigger an invalid write, but is indeed an array of `BUF_SIZE` bytes, which you document to be a reasonable value of 256. The problem is more likely with the stream pointer, which may be null as reported by Valgrind:

```
Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd`
```

You should fix potential undefined behavior in your code:

- verify if `fopen()` returned a valid `FILE*`, to avoid undefined behavior when you try to read from `input_file`.
- verify that `fgets()` succeeds (does not return `NULL`), to avoid undefined behavior when you read from the destination array.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. It also helped me to understand the situation better!